# Get rotation information when screenOrientation is fixed (Android, JAVA)

Tags: java, android

My AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".TestActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity"/>
```

When the mobile phone is placed horizontally in the vertically fixed mode, I want to get rotation information indicating that the screen is currently horizontal.

When I simply did the following, I could only know fixed rotation information.

```
((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you'll have to use `SensorManager` with `Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR`.

Register your `SensorEventListener` & then listen to updates on `onSensorChanged`.

I've created a sample code for you. I've added inline comments & links for your reference. You can click on the link & read what each function is meant to do.

Also, a large part of this code sample is from: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-use-android-sensors-to-detect-orientation-changes/

So, Please go there & read if you don't get something.

**Example Java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {

    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mRotationSensor;

    private static final int SENSOR_DELAY = 500 * 1000; // 500ms

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {
            mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Activity.SENSOR_SERVICE);
            mRotationSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR);
            mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mRotationSensor, SENSOR_DELAY);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Hardware compatibility issue", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor == mRotationSensor) {
            /*
             * This is a workaround for a large number of Samsung devices in the market that seem
             * to crash whenever more than four vectors are passed to Sensor Manager,
             * despite the Sensor Manager being the one to return more than four vectors.
             */
            if (event.values.length > 4) {
                float[] truncatedRotationVector = new float[4];
                System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, truncatedRotationVector, 0, 4);
                update(truncatedRotationVector);
            } else {
                update(event.values);
            }
        }
    }

    private void update(float[] vectors) {

        float[] rotationMatrix = new float[9];
        /*
         * Read more: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager#getRotationMatrixFromVector(float[],%20float[])
         */
        SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(rotationMatrix, vectors);


        int worldAxisX = SensorManager.AXIS_X;
        int worldAxisZ = SensorManager.AXIS_Z;
        float[] adjustedRotationMatrix = new float[9];
        /*
         * Read more: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager#remapCoordinateSystem(float[],%20int,%20int,%20float[])
         */
        SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(rotationMatrix, worldAxisX, worldAxisZ, adjustedRotationMatrix);

        /*
         * Read more: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager#getOrientation(float[],%20float[])
         */
        float[] orientation = new float[3];
        SensorManager.getOrientation(adjustedRotationMatrix, orientation);

        //converting radian to degree
        int roll = (int) ((orientation[2] * 180) / PI);

        //adjust 0 degree angle as mentioned in function desc
        roll = adjustOrientation(roll);

        Log.d("SD-Roll:", String.valueOf(roll));
        Log.d("SD-isHorizontal", String.valueOf(isHorizontal(roll)));
    }

    /*
     * Adjust orientation based on the default rotation degrees for the device.
     * For Some devices 0 degrees is landscape while on other 0 degrees is portrait.
     */
    private int adjustOrientation(int degrees) {
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        switch (display.getRotation()) {
            case (Surface.ROTATION_270):
                return degrees + 270;
            case (Surface.ROTATION_180):
                return degrees + 180;
            case (Surface.ROTATION_90):
                return degrees + 90;
            default:
                return degrees;
        }
    }

    private boolean isHorizontal(int degrees) {
        /*
         * when the degrees is 90 or -90. It means it's device is horizontal either on left side
         * or right side. But for practical usage you would want some range where you
         * start considering that this is landscape. Because as a user you're never going to
         * hold your device on perfect 90.
         *
         * For example I've taken 80 & 100. But you can change it according to what you think
         * is right for you.
         *
         */
        return (degrees >= 80 && degrees <= 100) || (degrees <= -80 && degrees >= -100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion worked wonderfully in my situation !! Thanks !!